# GridView - Open New Tab Custom Button with ID

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, devexpress

I have gridview which list of all our customers.Default edit button is not fit well with me.Can I add custom button for every row and on click opened in new tab with customer id.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use the **GridViewSettings.CommandColumn.CustomButtons** collection and handle the **GridViewSettings.ClientSideEvents.CustomButtonClick** event to accomplish this task.

Check out the full description [here](https://github.com/DevExpress-Examples/how-to-call-an-action-method-via-a-custom-button-and-pass-a-rows-key-as-a-parameter-e4827) and see how it works [online](https://codecentral.devexpress.com/e4827).

Answer (score -1):

I Think what after is custom command column, The following links should get you started.

https://documentation.devexpress.com/AspNet/3701/ASP-NET-WebForms-Controls/Grid-View/Concepts/Data-Representation-Basics/Columns/Command-Columns

https://demos.devexpress.com/aspxgridviewdemos/Columns/CommandColumnCustomButtons.aspx